# Existence of a pair of isomorphic subgraphs in a given graph with large number of edges

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random, random-graphs, probabilistic-method

I am trying to show that a graph $G$ with $n$-vertices and $pn^2$ edges ($n\geqslant10$, and $p\geqslant10/n$) contains  two vertex-disjoint and isomorphic subgraphs with at least $ap^2n^2$ edges, with $a$ a constant.

The solution I am trying to find involves the linearity of expectation but the computation of the probability for a random subgraph to be isomorphic to a given one seem complicated to compute.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: From the context, it is clear that $n$ is a positive integer. But, what about $p$ and $a$?

Comment: Hello @ajotatxe, $p$ is a positive real number greater or equal than $10/n$ s.t. $pn^2$ is an integer. $a$ must be a positive constant that doesn't depend on either $n$ or $p$.